# Synchronising multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have multiple tables which needs to be in-sync with the production database tables. Is there any way to ensure the data is synced with the production database other than manually updating the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the liquibase for this purpose. This is awesome tool for database

Liquibase is an open source database-independent library for tracking, managing and applying database schema changes. It was started in 2006 to allow easier tracking of database changes, especially in an agile software development environment.

[Wikipedia Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase)

[Liquibase Main Site](http://www.liquibase.org/)

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what database you are using, if it is MySQL then replication is the best option to sync.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, I set up Replication according to a answer that seems to be deleted. I also tried using SQLyog as he mentioned which also serves the purpose.